# 75 or 100 lb Drywall Anchors

Tags: drywall

I’m installing a wall pot rack.  I don’t know how the wt of rack, pots, pans, lids.  Should I use 100 lb to be sure, if 75lb is enough.  How much does it matter if you choose the heaviest anchor.

Comment: Neither, screw the rack into studs or wear steel toed boots/footwear.

Comment: How many pots?  What are made of?  iron, aluminum ? sizes?  There just is not enough information of anything other than a guess.  Please add to your question to give more pertinent info.

Comment: That’s all the info I have other than stainless steel and abt 15 pots, pans, and lids.  Sizes are 1 qt to 8 qt.

Comment: If you don't know the total weight, assume the worst and go with the highest load rated support possible - screwing directly into the stud.

Comment: Thank you for reading through my question and the bottom line answer.  Blessings.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have absolutely no alternative, don't use drywall anchors for anything more than a few pounds. **Screws into studs** is the way to go. Typical spacing is 16", though sometimes 24" and often there will be an extra stud somewhere *just because*.

If your wall does not have wood studs - e.g., if it is drywall directly over a brick or block wall then you will need do something different - but then your typical drywall anchors won't work anyway.

If the item you are trying to mount doesn't have holes at the right spacing, the usual workaround is to put a piece of wood on the wall across at least two studs and then mount the item to the wood. The wood can be stained or painted either to match the wall or to contrast with it.

Comment: Thank you.  I’ve hung this one piece before, in another house.  Of course the screws didn’t make the move or still packed. Dad would add the piece of wood. Even painting the wood, it looked cheesy.  Many thanks.